# multiple plugins on same message crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

How to register two plugins on same message? I am working on two plugins; one is updating status reason and the other is updating an attribute value. But when I register second plugin like the first plugin on same message I am seeing an error "error registering plugins and/or workflows".

Someone please guide me how to proceed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to register multiple plug-in steps for the same entity and message, so that itself isn't the problem.

There are several causes for the error you are getting. For example, this error appears if you register a plug-in assembly then make changes to its core code structure (e.g., change namespace, remove plug-in classes, etc.) and then try to register the same assembly over the one previously registered. The plug-in registration process expects to find the same classes that were previously registered. (Related details: [Error registering plugins and/or workflows. Plug-in assembly does not contain the required types or assembly content cannot be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277773/error-registering-plugins-and-or-workflows-plug-in-assembly-does-not-contain-th))

Please post more details, such as the full error you are getting in the plug-in registration tool, and step-by-step what you are doing. I've seen this error before and have always been able to work through it so with more details from you I or someone else can help you with this.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It is something very silly that I am doing might be the cause.
But my scenario is, I want to register 2 plug-ins on Merge message. One is to update statecode and the other is to update a lookup field of related entity called 'Task' based on the updated statecode. Parent entity is "Case".
For statecode, I used SetStateRequest to update and to update lookup field of the same record based on the statecode I had to write another plugin.

Comment: First plugin I registered and worked out successfully. But when registering second plugin I am doing the same process as first one; like selecting same primary entity, same message and everything is same.
This is where I am confused. Except the soluiton name and plugin names and code everything else I am doing is same. Probably I am overriding the plugin settings of the first one! How to register different plugins on same entity with same message? 
Thanks

Comment: If you unregister the first plugin are you then able to register the second?

Comment: Thanks guys..I've looked in the plugin registration tool. There is this second assembly already registered without step registered. I don't know how it happened. I usually deploy plugins from Visual Studio. Anyhow, I've unregistered the assembly from Plugin Registration tool and registered again. It worked this time!